# sql server 2005 installation on vista, COM+ error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

How to  Work Around COM+ System Configuration Check Failure in SQL Server Setup?

Answer (score 1):

There's an [MSDN article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143690%28SQL.90%29.aspx) with that exact question